# PostgreSQL with Sequelize acting weird with Timestamps

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timezone

I am new to PostgreSQL and using it for the first time with Sequelize package in NodeJS.

> My Local timezone: IST (+05:30)
>
> Sequelize timezone: UTC (+00:00)

**Model**

```
SomeModel = psql.define('SomeModel', {
    month: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'month'
    },
    uploadedDate: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        field: 'uploaded_date'
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'name'
    }
}, {
    tableName: 'some_table'
});
```

**Input data**

> month: 'Dec-2017'
>
> uploadedDate: '11-Dec-2017'

**Saved Data**

> month: '2017-11-30'
>
> uploadedDate: '2017-12-10 02:00:00'

I understand the month field UTC conversion sends it 5 hours 30 mins back in time so its November again but following this uploadedDate should be '2017-12-10 18:30:00'.
Why do PostgresSQL takes it to 02:00, what happened at 02:00?

Now one more weird thing I don't understand, when I try to fetch this same row values are changed again.

**Output Value**

> month: '2017-11-30'
>
> uploadedDate: '2017-12-09T20:30:00.000Z'

Now why does it converts already converted time again into UTC, just to increase my problems.

Please help what I am missing and how I can fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for few days I corrected it by doing following and understood the whole scenario.

- Column was not storing timezone (but it was not required in my case)
- Query was being fired 4 times which makes the date go to 2AM i.e. `5:30*4=22` which makes sense now
- Node was taking my server's localtime zone and converting it to UTC each time query fires.

The solution was converting the timezone of my server to UTC and everything worked like charm without any modification in the code.